# Carregar imagem no html a partir de caminho salvo no banco com django

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

Estou tentando fazer um jornal usando Django e banco MySQL e agora preciso listar as imagens das notícias:
No meu banco de dados eu tenho salvo o caminho da imagem, porque achei que assim teria um desempenho melhor do que usar uma ImageField.
Meu código está assim:

```
<body>
<h2>Notícias</h2>
<ul>
{% for noticia in Noticias %}
    <li>{{noticia.titulo}} - {{noticia.texto}} - {{noticia.imagem}}
    <img src="{{noticia.imagem}}" > </li>
{% endfor %}</ul>
```

Só que a imagem não aparece quando tento executar, existe alguma coisa errada no código? Ou será que o caminho da imagem está descrito de forma errada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso funciona se `noticia.imagem` tiver uma URL correta *e* que funcione para a sua imagem. Onde você está gavando as imagens? A app está configurada para servir arquivos estáticos de onde elas estão? É só abrir a página gerada no navegador, copiar o campo "src" da imagem, colar no navegador, e ver que não está funcionando - configurar até funcionar e pronto.

Só é possível responder até aqui, já que você não deu detalhes de onde estão as imagens de fato, e qual é o conteúdo do campo "imagem" (se é uma URL correta).

Detalhe que só trocar para ImageField, e colocar os arquivos de imagem em si no banco de dados não vai fazer mágica: você vai precisar de uma view para responder a URL das imagens e entregar só o conteúdo binário da imagem, e colocar a URL para essa view no campo `src` das tags `<img ...>`.

Answer (score 0):

Como foi dito acima, para conseguires carregar a imagem, o url dela precisa estar correto o que implica você ter um servidor de arquivos estáticos.
A melhor maneira para fazer isto seria utilizar uma **ImageField**, e configurando o **MEDIA_URL** e o **MEDIA_ROOT** no *settings.py* do projeto e depois incluir este url no *urls.py* do projeto.

veja como servir arquivos estáticos no django aqui [django-2.0-files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/files/)

Para uma **ImageField** faça as seguintes configurações e isto funciona perfeitamente:

Adiciona o **MEDIA_ROOT** e **MEDIA_URL** no *settings.py*

```
# projeto/settings.py 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# projeto/urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # incluir noticias.urls
    path('noticias/', include('noticias.urls')),
    # caminho para servir arquivos
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]


# noticiasapp/models.py
from django.db import models

class Noticia(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/images/noticias")
    texto = models.TextField()

# noticiasapp/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.listar_noticias, name="listar_noticias")
]


# noticiasapp/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Noticia

def listar_noticias(request):
    context = {'noticias': Noticia.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'noticias/listar_noticias.html', context)
```

*noticiasapp/templates/noticiasapp/listar_noticias.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Noticias</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    {% if noticias.count > 0 %}
        {% for noticia in noticias %}
            <li>
                <h3>{{ noticia.titulo }}</h3>
                <p>{{ noticia.texto }}</p>
                <img src="{{ noticia.imagem.url }}">
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <h3>Sem notícias ainda</h3>
    {% endif %}

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou corretamente.